# Error with iron router package

Tags: meteor, iron-router

For the first time I am using iron router package . Here my example code :

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});

Router.map(funtion(){
  this.route('home', { path: '/'});
});
```

When I run this app . It gives an error :

```
=> Errors prevented startup:
While building the application:
lib/router.js:5:22: Unexpected token {

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
=> Modified -- restarting.
=> Errors prevented startup:
```

I am not sure whats wrong with this simple code .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Router.map(funtion(){
  this.route('home', { path: '/'});
});
```

function is not spelled correctly.